# Seeking a formula for a counting problem

Tags: co.combinatorics

Suppose $cnt(i)$ represents the number of occurrences of $i$ in array $A$ of length $n$ whose elements are between $1$ and $n$. An array is called a $k$-good array if and only if $cnt(k)=k$ and $\forall i\not=k, cnt(i)\not=i$. Let $f(n,k)$ be the number of all $k$-good arrays of length $n$ whose elements are between $1$ and $n$.

For example, $4,2,3,3,3$ is a $k$-good array for $n=5,k=3$, but $2,2,3,3,3$ is not a $k$-good array for $n=5,k=3$, because $cnt(2)$ also equals to $2$ so you can't tell from what $k$ the array is derived.

I am wondering if there is a recursive formula for $f(n,k)$.

Comment: Hao, you may want to ask on https://math.stackexchange.com/ which is for "math at any level" (while MathOverflow is for "research level mathematics"). Before you do that, you'll want to clarify your question a little. Your quantity probably depends on both $n$ and $k$ so better call it $f(n,k)$. You could also work out some small cases manually and check if your sequence is in OEIS (https://oeis.org/).

Comment: I find a related problem in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3509979/number-of-functions-f-1-n-to-1-n-that-have-f-1-i-i, the only difference between them is that my problem requires only one k satisfying $cnt(k)=k$ which make it much harder.

Comment: Unless $n$ is a triangle number, there are 0 arrays. Then, if it is a triangle number, then the answer is a multinomial coefficient.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson Could you explain the details? At least $1,2,3,3,3$ is a good array for $n=5,k=3$ though $5$ is not a triangle number.

Comment: The question has been clarified but I still don't quite understand it. If the condition for $k$-good is that there are $k$ occurrences of $k$, then [2,2,3,3,3] is both 2-good and 3-good. Do you mean that there has to be exactly one such $k$ for the array to be $k$-good? This is not quite what the definition says.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen Yes, I mean there should be exactly one $k$, or else the array will not be considered as a good array. You should be able to know the unique $k$ from the array itself even if nobody tells you what $k$ it is.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry that I have given the wrong example in my comment, $1,2,3,3,3$ is not a good array, $4, 2, 3, 3, 3$ is.

Comment: @HaoHuang: 1, ; 1,2,2 ;  1,2,2,3,3,3 and 1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4 are good arrays, no? And 1, 3,6, 10 are triangle numbers. I do not see how 4,2,3,3,3 is a good array.

Comment: All of them are not good arrays. It may be better to understand in another way, You are to send a message to someone through an array, so he or she should recognize $k$ from an array itself, but $1,2,2, cnt(1)=1,cnt(2)=2$, so he or she doesn't know which number $1$ or $2$ is your message.

Comment: Thanks for clarifications Hao. Now the question makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

By standard properties of exponential generating functions, e.g.,
Sections 5.1-5.2 of *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 2, $f(n,k)$ is
the coefficient of $x^n$ in
$$ n!\frac{x^k}{k!}\prod_{\substack{i=1\\ i\neq k}}^n \left(
    e^x-\frac{x^i}{i!}\right). $$